# Ways to check @PreAuthorize in spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am currently checking authority like this.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasAuthority('GET_BOOK')")
@PostMapping("/find")
public Pagination<BookDTO> find(@Valid @RequestBody QueryCriteria queryCriteria) {
    return bookService.find(queryCriteria);
}
```

But I don't know if there is another way to check, I want to check in method.

```
@PostMapping("/find")
public Pagination<BookDTO> find(@Valid @RequestBody QueryCriteria queryCriteria) {
    // Check PreAuthorize here
      .....

    return bookService.find(queryCriteria);
}
```

Example as Entity Graph:

- 1 : There is a way to write : [image example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4e11.png)
- 2 : Another spelling is: [image example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc8gJ.png)

Thanks you !

Comment: please do not post images of text it is against the rules

Answer (score 0):

Checking authorization won't be good practice after all. But you can do with
following code snippets:

```
Object principal= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
 
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
  String username = principal.toString();
}
```

Here every time you need to do it manually and that will be a costly task!!

Here is content for more information about spring security :
https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture